# Laravel 5.8 dropdown value

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5.8

Below is the code which I use to render the drop down

```
<select class="form-control" id ="vendorCountry" name ="vendorCountry">
    @foreach($Country as $value)
       <option id ="{{ $value->id }}" {{ old('vendorCountry') == $value->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $value->mastervalue }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

When I submit my form, the value return is the selected test. Tried all combinations not sure where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added value inside option so may be you are facing issue, can you try below code.

```
  <select class="form-control" id ="vendorCountry" name ="vendorCountry">
        @foreach($Country as $value)
           <option id ="{{ $value->id }}" {{ old('vendorCountry') == $value->id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $value->mastervalue }}">{{ $value->mastervalue }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: @ramprathap-p let me know if you are still facing same issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue got fixed